# php --version gives me dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: php

I am a newbie to working with this problem.

I've been trying to set up php/apache/mysql on my Mac running 10.9 Mavericks. When I try to look at it (php --version) I get:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

irc.oftc.net responded that I need to install either imagemagick or libtool . It sounds like a possibility, but I'm not certain.

Can anyone give me more info on what to do?

Rick Eisner

Comment: looks like you are missing `libltdl-dev` package. `sudo port install libtool-devel` may work

Comment: if you have homebrew installed, you can use to install it with the 2 commands `brew install libtool --universal` and `brew link libtool`

Comment: Sorry, installing libtool-devel was not posssible: It returned "Error: libtool-devel has been replaced by libtool; please install libtool instead.
Error: org.macports.configure for port libtool-devel returned: obsolete port
Please see the log file for port libtool-devel for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libtool-devel/libtool-devel/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets"

Comment: So I tried installing libtool, which worked smoothly. But then, again, gave me "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap: 5"  I can't tell what's going wrong here... Any ideas???

Comment: bansi, I don't have homebrew installed. I read somewhere that it has several problems, and that macports was better (if a bit slower). It seems better not to confuse the issue.

Comment: You may be interested in this link I found at MacPorts Supports http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/21084